# Assigning values to patterns of letters in character strings using R

Tags: r, dataframe, character, assign

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
head(df)

   shotchart
1 BMMMBMMBMMBM
2 MMMBBMMBBMMB
3 BBBBMMBMMMBB
4 MMMMBBMMBBMM
```

Different patterns of the letter 'M' are worth certain values such as the following:

`MM = 1`
`MMM = 2`
`MMMM = 3`

I want to create an extra column to this data frame that calculates the total value of the different patterns of 'M' in each row individually.

For example:

```
head(df)

   shotchart           score
1 BMMMBMMBMMBM           4
2 MMMBBMMBBMMB           4
3 BBBBMMBMMMBB           3
4 MMMMBBMMBBMM           5
```

I can't seem to figure out how to assign the values to the different 'M' patterns.

I tried using the following code but it didn't work:

```
df$score <- revalue(df$scorechart, c("MM"="1", "MMM"="2", "MMMM"="3"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also split on "B" and base the result on the count of "M" characters -1 as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(shotchart = c("BMMMBMMBMMBM", "MMMBBMMBBMMB", "BBBBMMBMMMBB", "MMMMBBMMBBMM"),
                 score = NA_integer_,
                 stringsAsFactors = F)


df$score <- lapply(strsplit(df$shotchart, "B"), function(i) sum((nchar(i)-1)[(nchar(i)-1)>0]))

#     shotchart score
#1 BMMMBMMBMMBM     4
#2 MMMBBMMBBMMB     4
#3 BBBBMMBMMMBB     3
#4 MMMMBBMMBBMM     5
```

Answer (score 1):

We create a named vector ('nm1'), `split` the 'shotchart' to extract only 'M' and then use the named vector to change the values to get the `sum`

```
nm1 <- setNames(1:3, strrep("M", 2:4))
sapply(strsplit(gsub("[^M]+", ",", df$shotchart), ","), 
         function(x) sum(nm1[x[nzchar(x)]], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(score = str_extract_all(shotchart, "M+") %>% 
                        map_dbl(~ nm1[.x] %>% 
                                    sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
#      shotchart score
#1 BMMMBMMBMMBM     4
#2 MMMBBMMBBMMB     4
#3 BBBBMMBMMMBB     3
#4 MMMMBBMMBBMM     5
```